# Can I connect CoAPthon (CoAP of Python) to node-coap(CoAP for nodejs)?

Tags: python, node.js, raspberry-pi3, iot, coap

I am working on a raspberry pi project where I run python script and I want to send the sensor data from that script to my nodejs server.  I am trying to connect a CoAP server in python script to my client at the node server.  The libraries used are CoAPthon in python and node-coap in nodejs. When I try to connect the CoAPServer says  encoding is wrong any solution for this???
The error: "utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xbd in position 3: invalid start byte".
The python version of server that is CoAPthon server is as below.

```
#CoAPServer.py
from coapthon.server.coap import CoAP
from coapthon.resources.resource import Resource
gotin=1
class sensor(Resource):
    def __init__(self, name="sensor", coap_server=None):
        super(sensor, self).__init__(name, coap_server, visible=True,observable=True, allow_children=True)
        self.payload = str(gotin)
        self.content_type = "text/plain"
    def render_GET(self, request):
        return self
class CoAPServer(CoAP):
    def __init__(self, host, port):
        CoAP.__init__(self, (host, port))
        self.add_resource('/sensor', sensor())
def main():
    server = CoAPServer("0.0.0.0", 5682)
    try:
        server.listen(10)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Server Shutdown")
        server.close()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The nodejs CoAP client is as below.

```
//app.js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const path = require("path");
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));
var coap = require('coap');
var packet = require('coap-packet');
var req = coap.request({
  host: '127.0.0.1',
  pathname: '/sensor',
  port: 5682,
  method: 'get'
})
var payload = {
  user : 'ash'
}
req.write(JSON.stringify(payload));
req.setOption('Content-Format','text/plain');
console.log(req);
req.on('response', function(res) {
  console.log('response code', res.code);
  res.pipe(process.stdout)
});
req.end();
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Listening on port : ${port}`);
});
```

The error am getting is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\practice\raspberrypi\CoAPServer1.py", line 28, in <module>
    main()
  File "E:\practice\raspberrypi\CoAPServer1.py", line 23, in main
    server.listen(10)
  File "C:\Users\91948\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\coapthon\server\coap.py", line 153, in listen
    message = serializer.deserialize(data, client_address)
  File "C:\Users\91948\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\coapthon\serializer.py", line 57, in deserialize
    message.token = token_value.decode("utf-8")
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x91 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

Comment: Try to use wireshark to see what is acutally sent. it may be easier, if 5683 (standard) is used for coap, though wireshark knows that.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a bug in coapython -- there is no justification to assume that a token would necessarily represent anything in UTF-8 encoding. Please verify that this is still occurring in the latest version, and if yes report to the CoAPython developes.